# django - how do I handle exception for integrity error when deleting an instance?

Tags: django

I have two models, a Vehicle and an Asset where they are related with a one-to-one relationship.

Vehicle model:

```
class Vehicle(commModels.Base):
   
    vehicle_no = models.CharField(max_length=16, unique=True)
    vehicle_type = models.ForeignKey(VehicleType, related_name='%(class)s_vehicle_type', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, default=None, null=True)
    tonage = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=1, blank=True, default=None, null=True)
    asset = models.OneToOneField(
                        assetModels.Asset,
                        related_name='vehicle',
                        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                        null=True,
                    )
.....
```

Asset model:

```
reg_no = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    type = models.ForeignKey(AssetType, related_name='%(class)s_type', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
   
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        orgModels.Company,
        related_name='%(class)s_user',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
    )
```

When I delete a vehicle, the asset related to vehicle should be deleted as well.

My code for deleting vehicle:

```
@login_required
def vehicle_delete_view(request, id=None):
        
    obj = get_object_or_404(Vehicle, id=id)

    if request.method == "DELETE":
        try:    
            
            obj.delete() # this code causing an issue
         
            messages.success(request, 'Vehicle has been deleted!')
        except:
            print('exception triger-------')
            messages.error(request, 'Vehicle cannot be deleted!')
            return HTTPResponseHXRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))

    return HTTPResponseHXRedirect(reverse_lazy('vehicle_list'))
```

Now, I created a signal that deletes the asset tied to the vehicle upon successfully deleting it.

signal.py:

```
@receiver(post_delete, sender=models.Vehicle)
def delete_asset(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    print('signal is trigger')
    if instance.asset:
        asset = asset_models.Asset.objects.get(id=instance.asset_id)
        if asset: 
            print('asset is being delete')
            asset.delete()
```

On top of that, my vehicle has foreign key constraint on a few other models as well that points to it. When I create a new vehicle, it creates an instance for asset as well. So when I delete that said vehicle, it has no issue triggering the signal and delete it as well. So it works fine.

However, the issue I am facing if I try to delete a vehicle that is being referenced by other models besides Asset then it becomes an issue. The issue is there is a foreign constraint error but my try catch block could not catch it. Since it did not successfully delete the instance from Vehicle but yet it still triggers the signal. When it triggers the signal, it just prints `asset is being delete` and stays there forever.

I am confused as to why `post_delete` is being triggered in the signal since it did not delete the vehicle at all. Even when I tried to manually delete it from my database, I'll get an error:

```
/* ERROR:  canceling statement due to statement timeout
CONTEXT:  while locking tuple (27,15) in relation "vehicle_vehicle" */
```

I am trying to figure a way so that if `obj.delete()` throws an error(which it did obviously), I'll be able to catch it and handle it without even needing to trigger the signal since the vehicle is not being deleted. And so it should be able to redirect the request but instead there was no response at all on my page and still fires the signal.

Things I tried to catching a specific exception like:

```
from django.db import IntegrityError
        try:    
            # delete vehicle that are not referenced by other models
            obj.delete()
         
            messages.success(request, 'Vehicle has been deleted!')
        except IntegrityError as e :
            print('exception triger-------')
            print(e.__cause__)
            messages.error(request, 'Vehicle cannot be deleted!')
            return HTTPResponseHXRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))
```

The solution above yields no result and it just triggers my signal and "stuck" there as usual.

How do I handle this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Your `OneToOneField` is misplaced. If I understand your models correctly, you first create the Vehicle, then create the associated Asset. The `OneToOneField` would much better fit under the `Asset` model.

```
class Asset(models.Model):
    vehicle = models.OneToOneField(
                    Vehicle,
                    related_name='asset',
                    on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                )
```

This has multiple benefits:

1. You don't have to create the `Vehicle` with `asset = None` and do another query to set `asset` to the newly created asset.
2. When you delete a `Vehicle`, the `Asset` deletion will be handled automatically handled by Django since you defined `on_delete=CASCADE`.

Thus you won't have to do some weird gymnastic with signals to keep your integrity between `Vehicle` and `Asset`. Signals are quite unreliable for this kind of stuff. For instance, your signal wouldn't be called upon such statement `Vehicle.objects.filter(...).delete()`. In your case, I suspect the issue is some kind of circular dependencies which results in infinite SQL locks, or the signal was sent and executed in another transaction while the first one is not yet committed.

In any case, signals have several pitfalls and must be a last resort solution. Just have a look at all the warnings in the Django docs that advise to find a better implementation:

**[Signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/signals/#module-django.dispatch)**

> Signals give the appearance of loose coupling, but they can quickly lead to code that is hard to understand, adjust and debug.
>
> Where possible you should opt for directly calling the handling code, rather than dispatching via a signal.

**[Model signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/signals/#module-django.db.models.signals)**

> Signals can make your code harder to maintain. Consider implementing a helper method on a custom manager, to both update your models and perform additional logic, or else overriding model methods before using model signals.

> Many of these signals are sent by various model methods like `__init__()` or `save()` that you can override in your own code.
>
> If you override these methods on your model, you must call the parent class’ methods for these signals to be sent.
>
> Note also that Django stores signal handlers as weak references by default, so if your handler is a local function, it may be garbage collected. To prevent this, pass `weak=False` when you call the signal’s `connect()`.

---

If you really want to stick to your definition of the `OneToOneField` in the `Vehicle` model, I'd recommend, instead of using a signal, to do your deletion like this:

```py
if obj.asset:
    obj.asset.delete()
    # Deleting the asset will automatically delete the Vehicle as you set on_delete=CASCADE
else:
    obj.delete()
```

However, this is only a dirty workaround, and moving your `OneToOneField` to the `Asset` model will work much more seamlessly.

Comment: Thanks, in what situation is a good to use signals?

Comment: Some very specific cases might require the use of some kinds of signals, but in most cases there is a more reliable and maintainable alternative, especially for models signals. Afaic, in almost 10 years of professional Django development I have never had to use signals.